# How to handle or override the action of android device back button in flutter application?

Tags: android, flutter, android-layout, flutter-layout, accessibility

I want to navigate the user to home screen and delete the previous  navigation stack after pressed some button on another screen. For the time being I used Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil method for that. but the case is when I pressed the device back button on home screen my application crash So I wand to handle or override the device back button action.

Comment: You might want to include a stacktrace to make it easier for whoever wishes to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `WillPopScope` widget like this

```
return new WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
   //  your logic here 
   //  
   return Future.value(false); // true if you want the back button to take effect 
},
    child: new Scaffold(
     //then the rest of your code...
```